# Visual Studio Code debug python file stopped working

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Visual Studio Code debug Python file stopped working
I have been using visual studio code for years, and for no apparent reason debug stopped working.  It worked yesterday, but not today.  Here is what I do:

1. Double click a simple "Hello World" .py file.  It opens with visual studio code
2. Press arrow on the left side for run and debug
3. Select “Python File”.  Nothing happens
   [image]
4. Similarly, if I select the pulldown menu on the right and “debug Python file” nothing happens
   [image]
5. But if I select the pulldown menu on the right and “run Python file”, the program runs: a terminal opens, and hello world is printed.
   [image]
   [image]

How do I get debug to work (again)?

I tried reboot and reinstall.
Below is the version I am using
Version: 1.64.0 (user setup)
Commit: 5554b12acf27056905806867f251c859323ff7e9
Date: 2022-02-03T04:22:20.678Z
Electron: 13.5.2
Chromium: 91.0.4472.164
Node.js: 14.16.0
V8: 9.1.269.39-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19043

I am running on Window 10

Comment: it happened to me as well. It worked fine yesterday but not today. I just can't start debugger.

Answer (score 1):

I uninstalled VSCODE, **removed user .vscode directory**, and then reinstalled

Answer (score 0):

Start Anaconda Prompt and then type:

```
conda update --all
```

Python debugging will work after update to conda version > 4.9

Another option is to install previous version of python extension for VSC 2021.12
Both solutions does not requires reinstallation of VSC.

You can read more about this issue on:https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/18436